# Integrated CHATGPT text completion in node with react as frontend. API give me right answer but wrong on react interface. NS binding abort error

Tags: reactjs, cors, integration, openai-api

`

NS binding abort error on chatgpt api integration.
[image]

[image]

**Backend api code**

```
require("dotenv").config();


const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require("openai");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//start the server
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors({
  origin: "*",
  methods: ["GET", "POST"]
}));
//api key is passed of openai 
const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: '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',
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//connect to mongodb
const uri = "mongodb+srv://mongoapp-user:whoami11081@cluster0.oni0l.mongodb.net/customerdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
var con = mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "Connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("Connected Successfully");
});
//Chat gpt text generator api 
app.post("/ask", async (req, res) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  const prompt = req.body.prompt;
  //find the exist knowledge
  const result = await query.find({ prompt: req.body.prompt }, { completion: 1, _id: 0 });
  //return the existing knowledge
  if (result.completion) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: completion,
    });
  } else {
          try {
            if (prompt == null) {
              throw new Error("Uh oh, no prompt was provided");
            }
            const response = await openai.createCompletion({
              model: "text-davinci-003",
              prompt: prompt,
            });
            //get the new response for different question
            const completion = response.data.choices[0].text;
            //saving the first time response
            query.create({ prompt: prompt, completion: completion });
            return res.status(200).json({
              success: true,
              message: completion,
            });
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
          }
        }
});
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}!!`));
```

**Frontend code**

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [prompt, setPrompt] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const requestOption = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ prompt: prompt })
  }
  const fetchdata = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/bard", requestOption)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("ajeet");
        console.log(data.message);
        setMessage(data.message);
      });
  }
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    fetchdata();
  }
  useEffect((e) => {
    handleSubmit(e);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form >
        <input name="prompt" className="form-control input-inline" type="text" placeholder='Ask anything' onChange={(e) => setPrompt(e.target.value)} />
        <button type="submit" className="ask-button btn btn-primary" onClick={handleSubmit}>Ask</button>
      </form>
      <div id="answer" >{message}</div>
    </div>
  );

}
export default App;
```

I tried to remove the CORS problem but nothing can give exact response on interface as in postman. I am expecting chatgpt on integration give same answer or atleast logical answer on interface.

Answer (score 0):

I have to replace above code with this one. Problem with fetch code.

```
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Form clicked");
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/ask", requestOption)
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => {   
        console.log(data.message);
        setMessage(data.message);
        setPrompt("");
     });
}
```